# Doubt of solution: Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$, and $A\subset X$ is dense. Prove that $f(A)$ is dense in $Y$.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying for an analysis exam and this review problem has me stumped.

Prove that for $f:X\rightarrow Y$ continuous, and $A\subseteq X$ dense in $X$, then $f(A)$ is dense in $Y$. (I'm assuming $x$ and $Y$ are metric spaces since we haven't talked about anything else.)

The proof we were given goes as follows:

-Suppose $f(A)$ is not dense in $Y$. Then there exists $y\in Y$ and $\epsilon >0$ s.t. $B_\epsilon(y)$ does not intersect f(A).
-Then the preimage $f^{-1}(B_\epsilon(y))$ does not intersect $A$.
-But, $f$ continuous implies that the preimage of open sets is open. So, for any $x\in f^{-1}(B_\epsilon(y))$, we can find an open ball $B_\delta(x)$ that is contained in $f^{-1}(B_\epsilon(y))$.
-Now, $A$ dense in $X$ implies $B_\delta(x)$ intersects $A$. But $B_\delta(x)\subseteq f^{-1}(B_\epsilon(y))$ and $f^{-1}(B_\epsilon(y))$ does not intersect $A$. This is a contradiction.

Thus, $f(A)$ must be dense in $Y$. QED.

The thing I can't understand is that it seems to me that this proof assumes that $f$ is surjective. If $f$ is not surjective, then there may not by any $x$ such that $x\in f^{-1}(B_\epsilon(y))$, i.e. $f^{-1}(B_\epsilon(y)) = \phi$ and (I could be wrong) but it seems that epsilon balls and $\phi$ don't make sense.

For example, let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $f(x)=x^2$. Then certainly, $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. I can't possibly see though how $f(\mathbb{Q})$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

So, is the given proof correct? If so, what do I misunderstand?

Comment: You are exactly right; the missing assumption is that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Well, if it isn't surjective then the result isn't true.  If Y = R and f(X) = (0, 1) then there's no way in heck f(A) is dense in Y.  I think the assumption is that f:X -> Y means f(X) = Y.  Except of course that *isn't* the convention.  We write f:R -> R all the time for non-surjective functions.  So, yes, definitely an oversight.

Comment: It would also suffice if $f(X)$ is dense in $Y$ (instead of being all of $Y$).